# Obscure bash syntax error

Tags: bash, ssh

I am unable to find my syntax problem here:

```
» ssh bootstrap01 bash -c 'for master in master01 master02 master03 ; do ssh root@$master -i .ssh/master hostname ; done'
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
bash: -c: line 0: `bash -c for master in master01 master02 master03 ; do ssh root@$master -i .ssh/master hostname ; done'
```

### EDIT

To verify that my in-line script works:

```
$ for master in localhost localhost localhost ; do ssh $master hostname ; done

myhost.mydomain.net
myhost.mydomain.net
myhost.mydomain.net
```

Comment: Have you considered using `ProxyCommand` to forward SSH?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: thanks for the idea, but I would like to understand where my syntax problem is. `bash -c "xxx"` is explicitely telling ssh to use bash to run an in-line script. The in-line script itself is correct. Where is the problem then? Quoting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually a problem with the way that SSH passes the command to the remote side.  Compare these examples:

```
$ ssh localhost bash -x -c 'echo 1; echo 2; echo 3'

+ echo
2
3
```

```
$ ssh localhost bash -x -c "'echo 1; echo 2; echo 3'"
1
2
3
+ echo 1
+ echo 2
+ echo 3
```

The key to understanding the problem is that SSH reconstructs a command line from its arguments **and it does it badly**.  It just pastes the arguments back together using spaces, as can be seen if we run the two commands above with the `-v` option:

- ```
  debug1: Sending command: bash -x -c echo 1; echo 2; echo 3
  ```
- ```
  debug1: Sending command: bash -x -c 'echo 1; echo 2; echo 3'
  ```

respectively.

Obviously, the first of those is run (in the remote shell) as

```
bash -x -c "echo" 1
echo 2
echo 3
```

and that's what we see above.

In short, **you need to provide quotes for the remote shell**.

In your case, you'll probably be able to just omit the `bash -c`, as there's nothing in your command that a standard shell won't like:

```
ssh bootstrap01 'for master in master01 master02 master03 ; do ssh root@$master -i .ssh/master hostname ; done'
```

Comment: Great, removing `bash -c` solves the problem. I though I was making it better, and was actually making it worse